# How does bootstrap grid rows expand to enter page in retina displays

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Retina displays seem to the way of the future.

I am not able to understand how bootstrap grid system expands to cover entire pages ON RETINA DISPLAYS  when the container size is fixed to 1170 px. Refer to the link below.

```
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
```

Does anyone have any insight into this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459358/media-queries-on-retina-enabled-devices, from one of the commments: High resolution isn't for more real estate, its to make the images/text crisper. You don't get 2x the amount of pixels as far as width or height, if you want a 200px box, you make that box 200px and it will appear as 200px, but if that box has an image in it and that image is 144dpi (at least) then the image will be crisper. That's why it's best to use fonts for icons so that you're not creating lots of larger images. This is a very quick explaination

Comment: Expanding on that: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/20/towards-retina-web/ - "more better" explaination